# MongoDB query: If two docs are referencing each other, eliminate one doc (Keep one combination only)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have docs like these:

```
{
_id:61af43169dae3a9c3e133a90
name:"user1",
status: "RECOMMENDED",
recommendedId:61b708b8041895f4c68a3b3d
}

{
_id:61b708b8041895f4c68a3b3d
name:"user2",
status: "RECOMMENDED"
recommendedId:61af43169dae3a9c3e133a90
}
```

Both users are recommended to each other, so, I don't want both documents having recommended Id populated. I just want one document having recommendedId populated (Keep one combo only)

Answer (score 0):

I would try to prevent this from happening at the time of setting the value of `recommendedId` in the first place.

So before trying to set the value, you could do something like this:

```
const idToRecommend = Types.ObjectId()

const recommenders = await Foo.find({
   _id: idToRecommend,
   recommendedId: user._id
})

if (recommenders.length > 0) {
    // We don't want to make the change, we already have a relationship recorded.
}
```

Cleaning up a db already tainted with these duplicate relationships is a different question, but I would do that as a one-off task rather than a matter of process.